# zend framework 2: how to properly inject factory to controller to get different mapper classes?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I'm using Apigility, built on ZF2. Once request is dispatched to the controller's action, I need to choose proper adapter to hanle request - based on incomming parameters.

Normally, Controller is instantiated by `ControllerFactory`, where you can provide all dependencies, let say I need som kind of mapper class to be injected. It's easy, if I know, which one I will use in within the controller. It's problematic if I need to let controller decide which mapper to use.

Let's say user is requesting something like `getStatus` with param `'adapter1'` and another user is accessing same action, but with param `'adapter2'`.

So, I need to inject `adapter1` mapper OR `adapter2` mapper, which has similar interface, but different constructor.

What's the proper way how to handle this situation ?

On possible solution is to supply some kind of factory method, which will provide requested adapter, but - using the SM int the model class should be avoided.

Another way is to use SM directly in within Controller's action, but this in not best approach, because I can't reuse 'switch-case' logic for another actions / controllers.

How to handle this, please ?

Comment: I think you are able to access request object in your factory using SM. So just grab it and get your parameter and check condition before injecting dependency on your controller. Define Mapper Interface if needed if both adapter belong to common interface.

Comment: Thats not the case, unfortunately. Seems, that in Apigility are filtered params available only after action is call, not in constructor. I've tested this as first option :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use controller plugins for this.

Like that you can get the adapter inside your controller when you need it without injecting a `ServiceManager` and without adding all the logic to the factory. The adapter will only be instantiated when you request it in your controller action method.

First you need to create your controller plugin class (extending `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin`):

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

class AdapterPlugin extends AbstractPlugin{

    protected $adapterProviderService;

    public function __constuct(AdapterProviderService $adapterProviderService){
        $this->adapterProviderService = $adapterProviderService;
    }

    public function getAdapter($param){
        // get the adapter using the param passed from controller

    }
}
```

Then a factory to inject your service in the class:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin\Factory;

use Application\Controller\Plugin\AdapterPlugin;

class AdapterPluginFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceController
     * @return AdapterPlugin
     */
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceController)
    {
        $serviceManager = $serviceController->getServiceLocator();
        $adapterProvicerService = $serviceManager>get('Application\Service\AdapterProviderService');
        return new AdapterPlugin($adapterProviderService);
    }
}
```

Then you need to register your plugin in your `module.config.php`:

```
<?php
return array(
    //...
    'controller_plugins' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'AdapterPlugin' => 'Application\Controller\Plugin\Factory\AdapterPluginFactory',
        )
    ),
    // ...
);
```

Now you can use it inside your controller action like this:

```
protected function controllerAction(){
    $plugin = $this->plugin('AdapterPlugin');
    // Get the param for getting the correct adapter
    $param = $this->getParamForAdapter();
    // now you can get the adapter using the plugin
    $plugin->getAdapter($param);
}
```

Read more on controller plugins [here in the documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html)

Comment: Many thanks for explanation, seems, that this will be the best option for me. I'll accept the answer, just please one more question: do you think, that I can use SM directly in the plugin's getAdapter() method, instead of custom AdapterProvider ?

Comment: @Ivan, sure but it would than be better to inject your adapters into the controller plugin directly when instantiating it in the factory.

Comment: That's correct, but in scenario, where a lot of different adapters are available and just few of them are needed - will be possibly better to not instantiate all of them, but just requested.. it's a bit theoretical question, I'm just trying to choose best approach :) I'm trying to find some "lazy-load" factory approach, if you understand what I mean

Comment: @Ivan I hear you. Hard to say what is best in your case, but you could have a look at [ZF2 lazy services](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.service-manager.lazy-services.html).

Comment: Yes, this one is solving lazy-load, I agree and good to know, that there is something like that in place already :) Thing is, that I still need the "factory" pattern n within my provider service - otherwise I will need to instantiate (or lazy-instantiate) all known adapter (mapper) classes in the Factory of our provider. Only benefit is, that SM will be moved out of my "factory adapter chooser" to the service factory.. what is the benefit ? I'm trying to understand why using SM in the controller plugin is wrong thing :)